# Batch remove irregular suffix from folder names

Tags: powershell, rename, batch-rename

I have a series of folders named in the following fashion:

```
11.23 John Smith
12.912 Kate Spade
23.34 Alexander McQueen
22.E01 Michael Kors
```

I want to rename the folder names to just:

```
11.23
12.912
23.34
22.E01
```

The only consistency is that there is always a space between the digits and the person names.

I tried using this code below but it removes the prefix not the suffix:

```
Get-ChildItem | foreach {Rename-Item $_ $_.Name.Replace("Prefix", "")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | % { Rename-Item $_.FullName ($_.Name -replace '^(\S+) .*', '$1')}
```

Breakdown:

- `Get-ChildItem -Directory` - gets child directories
- `| % {}` - pipe them to `Foreach-Object` (`%`)
- `Rename-Item $_.FullName ($_.Name -replace '^(\S+) .*', '$1')` - rename based on full name (safer) to the name with a regex replacement. `^(\S)`  matches anything that's not a whitespace at the start of the string (`^`) as a group, followed by a space. `.*` matches anything after that.

Regex could be more robust if you want to make sure the folders match. E.g:

```
^(\d+\.[\dE]+) \w+ \w+$
```

Which matches numbers with decimal points that can have `E` in the 2nd part, followed by two words. That fits your examples, but not sure if it meets all the requirements that you need, so the one above is more reliable in terms of working.

Your code didn't accomplish anything, it tried to remove literally the word `Prefix` from the names.

Comment: This works perfectly! As II'm a total noob in PowerShell, I spent hours online searching for the answer. Finally I found you here on Superuser. You made my day!
You even took a step further explaining the codes in a breakdown, which is greatly appreciated. For a noob like me, this is gold! 

Have a beautiful day! :-D

Comment: @AustraliaX thank you for kind words and likewise!

Comment: `Rename-Item` receives the list of files so no need to use `%` or `ForEach-Object`

Comment: @phuclv I am aware, I forgot you can have functions for parameters like that. Doesn't matter too much though as the looping has to happen anyways, whether internally or like this, this will be just a little bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

In case there's always a space after the first field then you can use this

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.Name -split " ")[0] } -WhatIf
```

Aliased version:

```
ls -Di | ren -New { ($_.Name -split " ")[0] } -wi
```

`-WhatIf`/`-wi` is to do dry run, remove that to do real renaming

It's much simpler than using regex. The `-split` operator splits the name into an array and we just take the first token and use that as the new name for the folder

[Demo on TIO](https://tio.run/##tY3NCoJAHAfvPcWPxaAgF3ft0jGoS6IQHiNk0T/twvrBqhiUz75Z79BtmDlM107kek3Wes@E4DLGpdUN8toMmu3AhOQHIZGogZB3qqKvlDGP9zhaeqqmIoe0vI5EzS9Jfo4EUlNqRRZJ63qG9xovDO1YagQF5tUfT3iUBuHJLOSoQZjRtLw3QcEzVRPCvrNmAAPb3qI7ZoST8f4D)